# Passing complex object from angular js factory to web api using $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am passing an object to angular factory it is throwing error.

factory:

```
visitorApp.factory('loginRepository', function ($resource) {  

    return {
        VerifyVisitor: $resource('/api/VisitorWeb/VerifyLogin', {}, {
            query: { method: 'POST', params: {loginModel:loginModel}, isArray: true }
        })

    };

});
```

The complex object i am trying to pass is loginModel.

From controller call to factory.

```
visitorApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope,$location,$route,loginRepository) {
    $scope.submit = function (isValid) {
        if (isValid) {
            var loginModel = {
                UserName: $scope.UserName,
                PassWord: $scope.Password
            };

            var response = loginRepository.VerifyVisitor.query(loginModel);
            alert(response);

        }
    }
});

Error: loginModel is not defined
```

Web Api Method which is being called.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public string VerifyLogin(UserLoginDomainModel loginModel)
        {
            var msg = _loginService.Login(loginModel);
            return msg;
        }
```

Is it the right way of using $resource to post a request and pass complex object.

Comment: Is the error occurring in Angular or on the .NET side?

Comment: @MikeFeltman- the error is coming in file of factory in angular js. It is not able to get what is login model. So i want to know is im passing right or not and what is way then if not this.

Comment: Looking at the code you posted, you don't seem to be injecting the dependencies, shall we assume that's being done?

Comment: @rrd yes you can assume that

Answer (score 0):

Your service should look something like this:

```
visitorApp.factory('loginRepository', function ($resource) {  
    return {
        VerifyVisitor: $resource('/api/VisitorWeb/VerifyLogin', {}, 
        {
        query: {
            method: 'POST', 
            params: {loginModel: '@loginModel'}, 
           isArray: true }
       })

    };

});
```

The parameter variables are enclosed in quotes and prefixed with an @.

Comment: by using the above changes, it seemed to work. I am getting a call at server side too. I am calling this method by using this var response = loginRepository.VerifyVisitor.query(loginModel);. Now I am waiting from the response from the server and to do some thing with it. but the value is not coming in the response object

Comment: You probably want to set a breakpoint on the server at this point, inspect the incoming object and make sure it's what you expect, then go from there.

Comment: tHANKS FOR UR HELP- but what i want to explain was different.